How should I ask about the age of a colleague's young child?
Recapping the usual way that learners are taught expressions for asking someone's age: いくつですか is fine for kids, while お幾つですか has honorific function and is appropriate when your interlocutor is an adult, and 何歳ですか is of neutral politeness.
But if I were to ask an adult colleague for the age of their young child, is お幾つですか/何歳ですか the only option? In other words, is いくつ only fine if I'm speaking directly to a child?

It depends on what your relationship with your colleague is like.

So it's not about the referent at all (the child) but instead is about the relationship between you and the interlocutor?

You would need some context for いくつ to be understood as asking age. When this is given, 今いくつ, 子どもいくつ, and お父さんいくつ are all acceptable to me. You don't need much context when you are directly asking a small child.

As far as politeness is concerned, there isn’t a significant difference between 何歳 and 幾つ. 幾つ (without お) is indeed less commonly used with mature adults, but I think this is mainly because the "～つ" counting system only works with numbers up to nine. When asking your colleague about their child's age, いくつですか and 何歳ですか are completely interchangeable in conversation, though 何歳 would be preferred in serious academic contexts.
Whether to use お幾つ depends on the level of respect you need to show to the listener('s child). If you are talking with the president of your company, you probably should say お子様はお幾つですか. Otherwise, お子さんは幾つ(ですか) is usually sufficient, but adding お isn't strange, either.
